# Using multiple Bluetooth HCI simultanously in IoT Core UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, managed-c++, windows-10-iot-core

In UWP IoT Core, we can query remote Bluetooth devices as

```
    var DeviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

I want to know if we can specify HCI controller to query remote devices, we need to connect 1 Bluetooth LE device per HCI/dongle to maintain data rate @100hz.

If someone can suggest C# or C++ API, both are option for us.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your issue however for Bluetooth Low Energy devices I've done things like the following C# in my UWP app.

```
using System;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;

namespace WindowsIoTCorePi2FezHat
{
    internal class BleTagWatcher
    {
        private ulong tagNo;
        private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;

        private const short OutOfRange = -127;
        private short rssi;
        private DateTime lastDetected;

        public BleTagWatcher(ulong v)
        {
            this.tagNo = v;
            Rssi = OutOfRange;

            watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher { ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active };
            watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceipt;
            watcher.Stopped += (s, a) => { Rssi = OutOfRange; };
            watcher.Start();
        }

        private void OnAdvertisementReceipt(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.BluetoothAddress == tagNo)
                Rssi = args.RawSignalStrengthInDBm;
        }

        public short Rssi
        {
            get
            {
                //if (lastDetected.AddSeconds(20) < DateTime.Now)
                //    return OutOfRange;
                return rssi;
            }
            set
            {
                rssi = value;
                lastDetected = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can get lots more info from the devices advertisement of course. Not just the signal strength.

For info this was running on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Windows 10 IoT Core.

Hope this gives you a bit of a steer.